# Manipulating combBox depending on another comboBox Properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, c++-cli

I have two comboBoxes `comboBox1` & `comboBox2`. I would change some properties of `comboBox1` & `comboBox2` depending on the `SelectedItem` of `comboBox1`. I wrote the following code in `Form1_Load` block:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    if(this->comboBox1->SelectedItem=="Letters"){    

       this->comboBox1->Size=System::Drawing::Size(238,27);
       this->comboBox1->Location=System::Drawing::Point(301,73);
       this->comboBox2->Visible= true;

 }
 else{
       this->comboBox1->Size=System::Drawing::Size(473,27);
       this->comboBox2->Visible= false;
     }
}
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: Are you sure that code goes inside Form1_Load?

Comment: It is inside Form1_Load as It can be seen in my question.

Comment: What I meant was, is that code supposed to be inside the Form1_Load event? I think it should be under the comboBox1's SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: You are right! Thank you , your comment helped me!! but I don't know how to sign your comment as question answer!

Comment: You can do it now. :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that code supposed to be inside the **Form1_Load** event? I think it should be under the comboBox1's **SelectedIndexChanged** event.